# Linq remove all

Tags: c#, linq

Im trying to replace items in a list with the RemoveAll function, but didnt realize that it completely removes the index of the list. Is there a function that can replace objects instead of remove them? I am comparing strings.

```
  Items.RemoveAll(x => commonItems.Any(y => y.ItemName == x.ItemName));
```

Or maybe once its removed I replace it with another empty index at that same spot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could replace `RemoveAll` with `Where` to get the records you want to modify first:

```
var matches = Items.Where(x => commonItems.Any(y => y.ItemName == x.ItemName));
```

Then just iterate through the results and replace the value:

```
foreach (var match in matches)
    match.ItemName = "N/A";
```